# Cloud Bigtable bulk mutations failing for unclear reasons

Tags: google-cloud-bigtable, bigtable

I'm using the Java bigtable-client-core library, v1.12.0, and I'm trying to do a simple bulk mutation of rows as follows. Each of these is done from a transform in Apache Beam.

```
   try {
        client.bulkMutateRows(mutation);
    } catch (MutateRowsException e) {
        updateFailures.inc();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ApiException e) {
        updateFailures.inc();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I'm getting "Some mutations failed to apply" errors, and none of the data seems to be writing -a "cbt read" reveals no rows after it runs. However, I do see the write attempts on the web monitoring for the table. I don't know where to find any further information. How do I identify the source of the failures?

Answer (score 3):

Fixed - my mistake; the column family I was trying to write to had been removed from the table. Updates work fine now!

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the same issue and looked every where for the solution which didn't work for me as I've already checked the timestamp and column family are same. As per the documentation the mutations failed if the size is more than 100k. But in my case, I was processing 46k. So to debug the issue, I tried it first by doing it rowMutate() one by one instead of bulk mutation and it worked but that's very time consuming so then I created my own batch `List<BulkMutation> batchBulkRowMutation = new ArrayList<>();` and then processing those batch as in bulk mutation.
`

```
    List batchBulkRowMutation = new ArrayList<>();
    RowMutationEntry rowMutation = null;
    long btRowCounter = 0;

    try {
        BulkMutation bulkMutation = BulkMutation.create(bigTableId);
        for (Row row : dispatchPlanRowStream) { // reading data from other bigtable
        var rowKey = row.getKey().toStringUtf8();
        if (rowKey != null) {
                rowMutation = RowMutationEntry.create(rowKey);
                rowMutation = addingToBT(rowKey, rowMutation, row); // setting cell data for the column family in separate method, this is simple you can refer this in docs (calling setCell method and adding column family, qualifier, timestamp and value to it).
                bulkMutation.add(rowMutation);
            }
            btRowCounter++;

            if (btRowCounter % 20000 == 0) { // creating batch for 20k records
                batchBulkRowMutation.add(bulkMutation); // adding to the list
                bulkMutation = BulkMutation.create(bigTableId); // reassigning the value into bulkMutation to get other 20k records
            }
        }


        if (rowMutation != null) {
                // bulk mutation
            BigtableDataClient dataClient = GCPBigtableConnection.getBigtableDataClient(gcpProjectId, bigTableInstanceId);
            dataClient.bulkMutateRows(bulkMutation); // first processing the odd one records, let assume we have 50k records so for that we created 2 batch and the rest of records will be processed here or you can add those other records into the list as well to optimize the code.
      
            if (!batchBulkRowMutation.isEmpty()) {
                for (int j =0; j < batchBulkRowMutation.size(); j++) {
                    dataClient.bulkMutateRows(batchBulkRowMutation.get(j)); // processing the batch over here iterating the list of bulk mutations
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        log.error("Failed to write to BigTable process"); // print your own exception
    }
```

`
Not sure if there is any ideal solution but didn't find anything on this.